# Looping over webservice results not working

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to use a webservice and loop over the result set.
For some reason it only gives me back the first result which in this case is:

> Overall Rank: 537316 Level: 1419 Xp: 6407333

It seems to stop and not cycle through the rest of the results in the list of list which is from `stat_list` from the `grab_api` function.

`stat_list` is a list in a list with strings of numbers inside.

```
import urllib2
import re

def grab_api():
stat_list = []
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/index_lite.ws?player=taroboxx')
html = response.read()
stat_list.append(re.split(r"[,\n]", html))
return stat_list

def check_score(hiscore_html):
stats = ["Overall", "Attack", "Defence", "Strength", "Constitution", "Ranged", "Prayer", "Magic", "Cooking", "Woodcutting", "Fletching", "Fishing", "Firemaking", "Crafting", "Smithing", "Mining", "Herblore", "Agility", "Thieving", "Slayer", "Farming", "Runecrafting", "Hunter", "Construction", "Summoning", "Dungeoneering", "Divination"]
hiscore = 0
stat = 0
for i in hiscore_html[0]:
    if hiscore == 0:
        print stats[stat],
        print "Rank:", i,
        stat += 1
        hiscore += 1
    elif hiscore == 1:
        print "Level:", i,
        hiscore += 1
    elif hiscore == 2:
        print "Xp:", i
        hiscore += 1
    else:
        hiscore == 0

check_score(grab_api())
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` block you are doing `hiscore == 0` instead of `hiscore = 0`.

Comment: opps I actually had that changed in there. Even with that change in that section of the code it only produces the result for first 3 interations. I had it as: for i in hiscore_html[0]

Answer (score 0):

As an output of the first function your get a list of lists, so there is no iteration inside the list you want: you go to a list (hiscore_html), and inside you find one more list which is the only item of hiscore_html.

In order to avoid it, you can refer to the first element of hiscore_html. But I just saw your update -- it's exactly what you're doing, and the other mistake was fixed below.